pass lists data com from firebase from screen to other
The first code snippet for is for list of subjects and get data to pass to other screen by saving them in lists front_texts and back_texts. All data comes from firebase by function get_flashcard().
class ListSubject extends StatefulWidget {
  ListSubject({super.key});

  final front_texts = [];
  final back_texts = [];
  static const String list_subject_route = 'list_subject';

  @override
  State<ListSubject> createState() => ListSubjectState();
}

class ListSubjectState extends State<ListSubject> {
  void get_flashcards() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('flashcard').get().then(
      (QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
          //flip_cards.add(doc['front_text']);
          widget.front_texts.add(doc['front_text']);
          widget.back_texts.add(doc['back_text']);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[700],
      body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              get_flashcards();
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => SignUpScreen(
                      key: const Key('1'),
                      front_texts: widget.front_texts,
                      back_texts: widget.back_texts),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: const Text('biology'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

This is data viewer by card fliper and card swiper by same lists. I want to pass them to this screen, but always get empty lists. I don't know why and get error about length of front_texts, and nothing show.
class ListSubject extends StatefulWidget {
  ListSubject({super.key});

  final front_texts = [];
  final back_texts = [];
  static const String list_subject_route = 'list_subject';

  @override
  State<ListSubject> createState() => ListSubjectState();
}

class ListSubjectState extends State<ListSubject> {
  void get_flashcards() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('flashcard').get().then(
      (QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
          //flip_cards.add(doc['front_text']);
          widget.front_texts.add(doc['front_text']);
          widget.back_texts.add(doc['back_text']);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[700],
      body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              get_flashcards();
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => SignUpScreen(
                      key: const Key('1'),
                      front_texts: widget.front_texts,
                      back_texts: widget.back_texts),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: const Text('biology'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


"get error about length of front_texts" Please edit your question (there's a small edit link under it) and add the exact error message and complete stack trace you get.
